# Maximum value of a parameter in a cyclic inequality?

Tags: inequality, rearrangement-inequality

I want to figure out the set of possible values for $\alpha$ so that the inequality
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 + 2\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}x_{i+1} \ge 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually, you need to determine for which $\alpha$ the corresponding three-diagonal matrix $A(\alpha)$ is positive definite.

Comment: Yes, the motivation behind my problem is one from statistics, where $A(\alpha)$ is a matrix with diagonal equaling 1 and off-diagonals equaling $\alpha$. I couldn't figure out how to attack this problem with linear algebra techniques, so I've formulated it in terms of sums, as seen above.

Comment: Well, try to use Sylvester's criterion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: You can calculate all principal minors recursively (recurrence relation would be $d_n=d_{n-1}-\alpha^2d_{n-2}$ if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is written as $x^\mathsf{T} A x \ge 0, \ x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $A$ is a symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix.
(Note: The diagonal entries of $A$ are all $1$. The subdiagonal and superdiagonal entries of $A$ are all $\alpha$.)
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix

All eigenvalues of $A$ is
$$1 - 2\alpha \cos \frac{k\pi}{n+1}, \ k=1, 2, \cdots, n.$$

It is easy to prove that
$x^\mathsf{T} A x \ge 0, \ x\in \mathbb{R}^n$
if and only if
$$- \frac{1}{2\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1}} \le \alpha \le \frac{1}{2\cos \frac{\pi}{n+1}}.$$